# Reorganizing an array into a multiple dimension array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` containing objects

> [ObjA, ObjB, ObjC, ObjD, ObjE ...]

I'd like to create a 3xN dimension array like so:

> [ObjA, ObjB, ObjC]
>
> [ObjD, ObjE, ObjF]
>
> [...]

I just can't seem to wrap my ahead around my for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const NSInteger objsPerGroup = 3;
NSArray *flatArray = @[objA, objB, objC, objD, objE, objF];
NSMutableArray *groupedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:([flatArray count] / objsPerGroup)];
NSInteger index = 0;
NSMutableArray *currentGroup = nil;
for (id obj in flatArray)
{
    if (index % objsPerGroup == 0)
    {
        currentGroup = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:objsPerGroup];
        [groupedArray addObject:currentGroup];
    }
    [currentGroup addObject:obj];

    ++index;
}
```